# Add a test to each question in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

Hi
I want to automatically create a test for each question that is created in order to make the questions gradeable.
I already created a filter that displays a preview of the questions that they have made from the test but i cant manually create a test for each question.
is it possible to do it?
Thanks